# coordinates of the point where 2 tangents to a circle cross

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I have a circle of radius r.

Given two lines tangent to the circle at points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2),

What are the coordinates of the point where the two tangents cross?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_m,y_m)$ be the middle of $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. It turns out that the point $(x_p,y_p)$ you are looking for is a *multiple* of $(x_m,y_m)$ and that its distance from the origin is $r$ over the distance of $(x_m,y_m)$ from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Equation of tangent on circle $x^2+y^2=r^2$ at point $(x_1,y_1)$ is $$xx_1+yy_1=r^2$$

Similarly, tangent at $(x_2,y_2)$ is $$xx_2+yy_2=r^2$$

These are two linear equations which can be solved easily for intersection point